# Is the correct calculation of the bandwidth of TCP by having the value of the bandwidth of Ethernet?

Tags: tcp, ip, ping, ethernet, mtu

Is the correct calculation of the bandwidth of TCP (TCP / IP) by having the value of the bandwidth of Ethernet (ethernet_bandwidth)?

Part of productive bandwidth (except for headers):

> part_of_productive_bandwidth = (MTU - 40)/MTU

The time required to reply within one second:

> time_took_for_reply = (ethernet_bandwidth/TCP_receive_window)*ping

Part of the productive time (except for expectations replies):

> part_of_productive_time = (1 - time_took_for_reply) / 1

**Real bandwitdh:**

> real_bandwitdh = ethernet_bandwidth * part_of_productive_bandwidth * part_of_productive_time

Or:

```
real_bandwitdh = ethernet_bandwidth * (MTU - 40)/MTU * 
    (1 - (ethernet_bandwidth/TCP_receive_window)*ping)
```

For example for:

```
ethernet_bandwidth = 1 Gbit/s = 125 000 000 B/s
MTU = 1500 B
TCP_receive_window = 128 KB = 131072 B
ping = 0.001 sec

real_bandwitdh  = 125 000 000 * (1500-40)/1500 * (1 - (125 000 000/131072)*0.001) = 
    125 MB/s * 0.973 * 0.046 = 5.59 MB/s
```

Is it true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not stick with TCP layer stats? Number of packets sent * MTU divided by the time taken. Basically, TCP layer does **explicitly** not take into account any bandwidth. The whole send-rate estimation (aka window-size variation) is based on how many packets (in what stage - slow-start, congestion-avoidance) go through without hitting retransmission.

Comment: But if we using `Selective Acknowledgement (RFC 2018)`, which turn off slow-start and disable variation of window-size, then my calculations are close to the truth? I want to understand at a theoretical level, why does the significant decrease in the rate if there is no packet loss.

Comment: Can you please confirm that SACK turns off slow-start and disables variation of window-size? Can you please point me to the document (page/para number, if possible). As far as I know, SACK simply provides a broader ACK of upto 3 packets that it has lost. Even if you use SACK, TCP still does not revert to using local LAN parameters. TCP is an end-to-end transport protocol and using slow-start/congestion-avoidance/recovery, it indirectly estimates the bandwidth.

Comment: Btw, there is a variation of TCP called TFRC, that does estimate the bandwidth: http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3448 . It still does not use LAN characteristics, but instead uses packet loss, RTT, and timeout.